# Get location/position of an element

Tags: ruby, watir

I use watir-webdriver and try to find the position of an element like `$browser.div(:id, "foo")`.  When i try to click on it, the chromedriver says

> Element is not clickable at point(-1707, -799.5)

How is it possible to get this coordinates of the element? I tried this:

http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Right+Click+an+Element

But I get an error when I tried to call the `document()` method.

Comment: Dead link, but archived at http://web.archive.org/web/20130516055542/http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Right+Click+an+Element

Answer (score 10):

I assume you are using Watir-Webdriver since you are using Chromedriver. The article you reference is actually for Watir, which is not always the same as Watir-Webdriver.

To get an element's location, you can use the `Element#location` method:

```
location = browser.element(:id, 'id').location
puts "location x = #{location.x}"
puts "location y = #{location.y}"
```

Note that older versions of Watir-Webdriver do not have this method. Instead, you'll need to directly access the underlying Selenium::WebDriver:

```
location = browser.element(:id, 'id').wd.location
puts "location x = #{location[0]}"
puts "location y = #{location[1]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

i think that location (.wd.location) is a relative location which is within the browser page range, not the absolute location of the system screen.

say, it gets (700, 300) as your browser is maximized.
but it gets (500,200) as your browser is moved....

i got a button's "wd.location" and then sent a mouse-click event from Autoit"autoit.MouseClick("left", x, y)". I found the mouse is out of the button.
I must add an offset to fix it, but real problem is that offset changes with my browser location...